# Is there a function in Python or Pandas that allows you to consolidate multiple different row values into one using a wildcard?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reclassify a multi-select survey response into binary columns with the new values, but the amount of unique Other columns is the reason for the issue.

I am trying to change

```
Row #   Column #     
0       Fun      
1       Fun, Easy      
2       Easy, Other [confusing]
3       Fun, Other [difficult to use]
4       Fun, Easy, Other [annoying]
```

into

```
      Fun       Easy      Other
0      1          0         0
1      1          1         0
2      0          1         1
3      1          0         1
4      1          1         1
```

I've been using the below code to separate into dummies, but I'm looking for a solution to consolidate all the 'Other [values]' into just one 'Other.'

```
df.iloc[:, 0].str.get_dummies(',')
```

but this produces

```
      Fun       Easy      Other [confusing]  Other [difficult to use] ....
0      1          0         0                 0
1      1          1         0                 0
2      0          1         1                 0
3      1          0         0                 1
4      1          1         0                 1
```

which quickly becomes unwieldy with multiple and sparse other responses.

Comment: Cant you split the Other part into two columns retaining the details for future reference. That way you can summarize others count

Answer (score 3):

You can replace all the `Other [...]` with `Other` before `str.get_dummies`:

```
(df['Column #'].str.replace('Other \[.*\]', 'Other')
    .str.get_dummies(', ')
)
```

Output:

```
   Easy  Fun  Other
0     0    1      0
1     1    1      0
2     1    0      1
3     0    1      1
4     1    1      1
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you for the help. I needed to remove the space in the above code you provided to get it to work. I then joined the above new dummy columns into the old one, and removed the old column via the drop method. Thanks again, Quang!